# Macro or VBA to reuse or repeat a footnote with user selecting the footnote from the table?

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, macros

I made a macro to insert the number of an existing footnote, but the captured command in the macro contains the number of the footnote from when the macro was recorded.
I am looking for a method that lets the user position the cursor to the desired location and then select the macro. The macro displays the footnote list from the crossreference command and lets the user select the desired footnote and continue from there.
Essentially I want the macro to open the crossrefence dialog, preset Reference type to footnote, uncheck Insert as hyperlink, select Insert reference to: Footnote number (formatted) and wait for the user to select For which footnote: and click Insert.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! We are not a free coding service but a community of people interested in computers that are willing to share their knowledge and experience. If you post what you already tried, you will more likely get a satisfying answer as it is most often easier to improve existing code than to write new from scratch.

Comment: Mostly looking for someone to say it can or can't be done. I might need to put some VBA in to simulate the dialog and then pass the selections to the real command.